# DNs not editable after setting parent router in bridge mode

Tags: router, wireless-router, bridge-router

After I enabled bridged mode on the provider router the dns of my router is not editable, why is that?

Internet Provider Router **(Bridge mode enabled = true)** -> My Router

The setup of my router appears like:

[image]

Which is weird, in theory, this is the router that is working, and the other just as a bridge... or what?

Comment: You set bridge mode so that a different router would have control right?  Set DNS in that different router....

Comment: this is the setup of my router, the one with bridge mode true is the internet providers one.

Answer (score 1):

A router in Bridged Mode won't make use of those settings anyway. You will need to set DNS and any other services you want on the device you are bridging to.

Comment: this is the setup of my router, the one with bridge mode true is the internet providers one.